# JScrollPane is not displaying when hide and shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-jscrollpane

Please check this code: http://jsfiddle.net/rkumarnirmal/Rq7b2/2/

What I'm doing is I'm showing some text. If the text is clicked then the list will be displayed with Jscrollpane. But here the list is shown and the jscrollpane is not displayed.

What mistake I've done there? could anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to re-call it when the content changes,

http://jsfiddle.net/Rq7b2/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can set the JScrollPane to auto-reinitialize.

http://jsfiddle.net/L7KSa/

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html

> autoReinitialise - boolean (default false)
>
> Whether jScrollPane should automatically reinitialise itself periodically after you have initially initialised it. This can help with instances when the size of the content of the scrollpane (or the surrounding element) changes. However, it does involve an overhead of running a javascript function on a timer so it is recommended only to activate where necessary. Demo.